# center a string by padding spaces up to a specified length

Tags: r, string, formatting, printf, string-formatting

I have a vector of names, like this:

```
x <- c("Marco", "John", "Jonathan")
```

I need to format it so that the names get centered in 10-character strings, by adding leading and trailing spaces:

```
> output
# [1] "  Marco   " "   John    " " Jonathan "
```

I was hoping a solution less complicated than to go with `paste`, `rep`, and counting `nchar`? (maybe with `sprintf` but I don't know how).

Comment: Here's a complicated one: `paste(sapply(nchar(x), function(n) paste(rep(" ", floor((10 - n)/2)), collapse = "")), x, sapply(nchar(x), function(n) paste(rep(" ", 10 - n - floor((10 - n)/2)), collapse = "")), sep = "")`

Comment: @d.b thanks, your solution works indeed (except when the initial names exceed 10 char it throws an error).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a `sprintf()` solution that uses a simple helper vector `f` to determine the low side widths.  We can then insert the widths into our format using the `*` character, taking the `ceiling()` on the right side to account for an odd number of characters in a name.  Since our max character width is at 10, each name that exceeds 10 characters will remain unchanged because we adjust those widths with `pmax()`.

```
f <- pmax((10 - nchar(x)) / 2, 0)

sprintf("%-*s%s%*s", f, "", x, ceiling(f), "")
# [1] "  Marco   "  "   John   "  " Jonathan "  "Christopher"
```

Data:

```
x <- c("Marco", "John", "Jonathan", "Christopher")
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to print a string with **centering align** and **padding** with `#`.

```r
stringr::str_pad("hello", 20, side = "both", pad = "#")
```

It will output:

```
[1] "#######hello########"
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I know it's not the same language, but it is Worth noting that **Python** (and not R) has a built-in method for doing just that, it's called centering a string:

```
example = "John"
example.center(10)
#### '   john   '
```

It adds to the right for odd Numbers, and allows you to input the filling character of your choice. ALthough it's not vectorized.