# Left-align and right-justify text using draw_label

Tags: r, ggplot2

When using draw-label, is there anyway to left-align and right-justify text similiar to what ms word does?

[image]

Desired end-result style text:

[image]

```
chart <- mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = hp, y = cyl)) +
  geom_point()

label <- ggdraw() +
    draw_label(label = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt\nut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco\nlaboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo.",
               size = 8,
               hjust = 0, 
               x = 0.05)

plot_grid(label,
          chart,
          ncol = 1)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [center a string by padding spaces up to a specified length](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44730318/4752675)

Comment: This looks more like a caption to me rather than a label, i.e., more suitable as part of a report / document. You can (and maybe should) use something like Rmarkdown - and simply knit to html with knitr, or to pdf via latex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this with `cowplot` 's `draw_label` you may use `rel_heights`, see below.

But as @Tjebo pointed out the text chosen is maybe a bit long for a figure caption - see second part.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(cowplot)

chart <- mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = hp, y = cyl)) +
  geom_point()


p1 <- ggdraw() + 
  draw_label(label = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
             sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt\nut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco\nlaboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo.",
             size = 8)

# You can use **rel_heights**
plot_grid(p1, chart, ncol = 1, align = "h", rel_heights = c(1,4))
```

[image]

```r
# Text is a bit long for a figure caption and should somewhere else
# But you could use title, subtitle and caption, which you can move
chart + 
  labs(caption = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
       title = 'LOREM IPSUM',
       subtitle = '... dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit') +
  theme(plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 1, face= "italic"), 
        plot.title.position = "plot", 
        plot.caption.position =  "plot")
```

[image]

**References**

- [wilkelab](https://wilkelab.org/cowplot/articles/aligning_plots.html)
- [Rcommunity](https://community.rstudio.com/t/positioning-legend-when-using-plot-title-position-plot/49496)